# Derivative of (Norm of) Möbius Addition w.r.t. Curvature

Tags: special-relativity

Does anyone know a resource showing the formula for the derivative of the (norm) of the Möbius addition?

This is the Möbius addition:
$$
x \oplus_cy=\frac{\overbrace{(1+2c\langle x,y\rangle+c||y||_2^2)}^{A(c)}x + \overbrace{(1-c||x||_2^2)}^{B(c)}y}{\underbrace{
1+2c\langle x,y\rangle + c^2||x||^2_2||y||^2_2}_{D(c)}}
$$

What is

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial c}(x\oplus_c y)
$$

or

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial c}( ||x\oplus_c y||_2)
$$
?

---

So far what I've found is:

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial c }
(x\oplus_c y)
=
\frac{A'(c)x+B'(c)y+D'(c)(x\oplus_c y)}{D(c)}
$$

How can this expression be interpreted in gyrovector space notation?

---

The expression $\sqrt{c}||(-x)\oplus_c y||_2$ represents the geodesic length between $x$ and $y$.

Now what would be its derivative w.r.t. $c$? The change in geodesic length between $x$ and $y$ depending on the curvature $c$, right?

Is that expressible in some way in the gyrovector notation?

Answer (score 1):

Using a slightly modified version of your addition (but equivalent):
$$x \oplus_K y = \frac{(1-2K\langle x, y\rangle - K||y||^2)x + (1+K||x||^2)y}{1-2K\langle x, y \rangle + K^2 ||x||^2 ||y||^2}$$

After doing symbolic differentiation using Mathematica:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial K} (x \oplus_K y) = \frac{
(2\langle x, y \rangle + ||x||^2 - 2K||x||^2||y||^2-K^2||x||^4||y||^2)}{(1-2K\langle x, y \rangle + K^2 ||x||^2 ||y||^2)^2}y + \frac{(-||y||^2-2K||x||^2||y||^2 + 2K^2 \langle x, y \rangle ||x||^2||y||^2 +K^2||x||^2||y||^4)}{(1-2K\langle x, y \rangle + K^2 ||x||^2 ||y||^2)^2}x.$$
Unfortunately, I don't really see a way to simplify it much.
With some more notation, we can get
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial K} (x \oplus_K y) = \frac{
(2\langle x, y \rangle + ||x||^2 - 2\alpha-K||x||^2\alpha)}{(1-2K\langle x, y \rangle + K\alpha)^2}y + \frac{(-||y||^2-2\alpha + 2K \langle x, y \rangle \alpha +K||y||^2\alpha)}{(1-2K\langle x, y \rangle + K\alpha)^2}x,$$
where $\alpha = K||x||^2||y||^2$, but that doesn't really help much.

---

Original Mathematica code:

```
kplus[x_,y_,K_]:=((1-2K*Dot[x,y]-K*Norm[y]^2)*x+(1+K*Norm[x]^2)*y)/(1-2K*Dot[x,y]+K^2*Norm[x]^2*Norm[y]^2);
Expand[Simplify[D[kplus[x,y,K],K]]]
```

and the original result:

```
(-x Norm[y]^2 - K^2 y Norm[x]^4 Norm[y]^2 + 2 x.y (y + K^2 x Norm[x]^2 Norm[y]^2) + Norm[x]^2 (y - 2 K (x + y) Norm[y]^2 + K^2 x Norm[y]^4)) / (1 - 2 K x.y + K^2 Norm[x]^2 Norm[y]^2)^2
```

Comment: That looks really great. The nice thing is that the denominators in both addition terms resemble the ones from the möbius addition, except that they are squared. Maybe that can be re-cast even more to Gyrovector notation.